# Is $f_{n}(x)=sin(\sqrt{x+4\pi^2 n^2})$ uniformly convergent on $x\in(0,b)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

I want to prove that $f_{n}(x)=sin(\sqrt{x+4\pi^2 n^2})$ is uniformly convergent in $x\in(0,b)$. I have already seen that it is pointwise convergent with limit $0$. But now I have to look for an upper bound for $|f_{n}(x)|$ for $x\in(0,b)$.

$$sup_{x\in(0,b)}|sin(\sqrt{x+4\pi^2 n^2})|$$

I cannot find an upper bound and I'm starting to suspect that it is not uniformly convergent. I tried deriving but this doesn't give me any information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that $\sin(\sqrt{4 \pi^{2}n^{2} + x})$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833814/showing-that-sin-sqrt4-pi2n2-x-converges-uniformly-on-0-1) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f_%7Bn%7D(x)%3D%5Csin(%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B4%5Cpi%5E2%20n%5E2%7D)%24)

Comment: Yes, thank you!!